# Convert date Format yy/totaldaysinyear/totalsecondsinday to dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss

Tags: java, date-format, date-formatting

I have this format YY/Number of date : **14 316 57627**
**14** : is the year 2014
**316** : is the number of the day within the year
**57627** : is the number of seconds passed since the beginning of the day

I need to recover to dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss date format

The question is if there is some Java method or library that can calculate that.

Comment: 31657627 is the number of seconds passed since the beginning of the year ?

Comment: (20)14 year, 316 number of the day in the year, 57627 number of the seconds in the day.

Comment: I need to calculate the day and month with the 316 and the year

Comment: and the Hour, minutes and seconds with: 57627 in the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two elements to this question.  First you need to calculate the appropriate Date value from your input format, which you should be able to do using `java.util.Calendar`:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 2000);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayNumber);
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, numSeconds); // add handles overflow from one field to next
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Once you have the right date you can format it however you like using a `SimpleDateFormat`.